# Как скачать последний коммит из GitHub на компьютер через GitHub Desktop?

Tags: github, desktop

Сделал коммит в облако, сделал много пробных изменений, хочу вернуться обратно к последнему коммиту. Как это сделать через GitHub Desktop?

Comment: Коммиты ты делаешь локально, а потом можешь их пушить на удаленную репу. Если хочешь откатить, сделай чекаут. Перед этим можно закинуть в stash.

Comment: Не пользуйтесь GUI для Git'а, лучше сразу терминал. GUI удобно разве что на ветки смотреть. Больше никакого профита.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Боюсь, что никак, см. [такой же вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34791029/5308802) – GitHub Desktop это не полноценный GUI клиента GIT'a, он позволяет делать лишь базовые операции с коммитами и ветками. Решение: используйте либо другой графический клиент(например, [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) (Win) или [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (Mac, Win)), либо напрямую консольную утилиту, где такие вещи делаются одной командой вроде `git reset --soft HEAD~1` или `git reset f7823ab`.